# asp.net core ioptions with a dictionary

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, appsettings

I'm trying to read Letters as **Dictionary** from the appsettings.json file. My json contains:

```
    "Words": [
      "Alpha",
      "Beta",
      "Gama"
    ],
    "Letters": [
      { "A": "Alpha" },
      { "B": "Bravo" },
      { "C": "Charlie" }
    ],
```

I use configuration class:

```
public class AppSettingsConfiguration
{
    public List<string> Words { get; set; } = default!;
    public Dictionary<string, string> Letters { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

property **Words** is corrected read from .json, but **Letters** throw exception 'Cannot create instance of type 'System.String' because it is missing a public parameterless constructor.'

If I tried

```
List<(string, string)> Letters { get; set; }
or
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Letters { get; set; }
```

I get all 3 lines, but all empty - (null, null)

What is correct property for reading dictionary?

Comment: Saddly yhe model that match this data is `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`. Nothing stop data too look like `{ "A": "Alpha" }, 
    { "A": "Alpha", "B": "Bravo" },
    { "B": "Bravo" }`. So it's not `KeyValuePair<string, string>` but a full Dictionary there.

Comment: `Letters` is an array, not a dictionary. It contains elements with properties named `A`, `B`, `C`, etc, so it can't be deserialized into a `KeyValuePair` class whose properties are named `Key` and `Value`. A dictionary would be `"Letters": { "A":"Alpha","B":"Bravo",...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary is serialized differently in C#. Please see following JSON:

```
"Letters": {
  "A": "Alpha",
  "B": "Bravo",
  "C": "Charlie"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saddly The model that match this data is `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`.
Nothing stop data too look like:

```
{
    "Words": [
        "Alpha",
        "Beta",
        "Gama"
    ],
    "Letters": [
        { "A": "Alpha" }, 
        { "A": "Alpha", "B": "Bravo" },
        { "B": "Bravo" }
    ]
}
```

So it's not `KeyValuePair<string, string>` but a full Dictionary there.

If you want to get back to `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` you can use a simple `SelectMany(x=> x)`

Live Demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/CFtWm3